# Не создаются скриншоты в Allure-отчете (python + pyautogui)

Tags: python-3.x, allure, pytest, pywinauto

Всем здравствуйте. Возникает такая проблема при генерации Allure-отчета с использованием pyautogui. Файл скриншота в папке создается, но изображения нет, также сам тест фейлится. Подскажите пожалуйста, в чем может быть проблема? Заранее спасибо.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Убедительная просьба не постить код только в скриншотах, код плохо читается и невозможно ничего скопировать, а набирать куски кода по картинке никто не будет. Если вставляешь скриншот, убедись, что код доступен и в виде текста.

Comment: Тег pywinauto относится к совершенно другой библиотеке, pywinauto - это не pyautogui. Для полноты картины список известных мне подобных тулов здесь: https://github.com/pywinauto/pywinauto/wiki/UI-Automation-tools-ratings (рейтинг обновляется раз в месяц)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в несовместимости типов. `pyautogui.screenshot()` возвращает объект `PIL.Image`, который `allure` не знает, как сохранять. Перегони `Image` в массив байтов:

```
import io

with allure.step('fizz'):
    fp = io.BytesIO()
    image = pyautogui.screenshot()
    image.save(fp, format='PNG')
    raw = fp.getvalue()
    allure.attach(raw, name='screenshot', attachment_type=AttachmentType.PNG)
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! =)

Comment: Рад был помочь!